# useAuthStateChange isn't updating state in useEffect Supabase

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-hooks, expo, supabase

Using expo and supabase (no typescript), I am trying to call useAuthStateChange inside a useEffect hook to update useState with the session. From what I understand, this is the most common approach

Logging in and signing up both work, according to Supabase Postgres logs, but I believe useAuthStateChange may be firing upon page load and then not refiring.

Here is my code. Please let me know if I am missing something:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
            setSession(session);
        });

        supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(({ data: { session } }) => {
            setSession(session);
        }); 
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed this initialisation recommendation for Expo/React native: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-expo#initialize-a-react-native-app ?

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = YOUR_REACT_NATIVE_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseAnonKey = YOUR_REACT_NATIVE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, {
  auth: {
    storage: AsyncStorage as any,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: false,
  },
})
```

Then this should work:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setSession(session)
    })

    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setSession(session)
    })
  }, [])
```

Looking at your code above, I think you're accessing the session incorrectly in the `onAuthStateChange` callback.